# Is there a limit to SQL statements when done through a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL query that consists of lots of SQL statements separated by semicolons. When I run the query through phpmyadmin it works fine. However when I do it through a PHP script, I get a message saying there is an error in my SQL syntax? Is there a limit to the length of the query when done through PHP?

Comment: by default, php's mysql drivers only allow a single statement per query() call. this is a basic defense mechanism against one form of sql injection attack. and otherwise, yes, there's a length limit to queries, set by mysql's `max_allowed_packet`. that's not a php limit, it's a mysql limit.

Comment: Run this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` The unit is in `Bytes`

Comment: Post that error here

Comment: Do You use `mysqli_multi_query` ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a limit in MySQL configuration: max_allowed_packet in my.cnf file.
Try to set a bigger packet size.